# UIButton inside UITableViewCell setHighlighted not updated on table scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, uicontrol, touches

I have a subclass of UIButton placed inside a UITableViewCell's contentView.  The problem I am having is that when I press the button and scroll the table (quickly) the button's `setHighlighted:` method gets called three times, all with `YES` as the parameter.  The button never gets de-highlighted when the table scrolls (so when I finish the scroll one of my buttons looks like it's depressed, but there are no longer any fingers on the screen).  If I press the button, wait a second, and then scroll the table does not scroll and the button gets de-highlighted properly (when the touch event exits the button's frame).

I have tried setting the tableView to

```
self.tableView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
self.tableView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

But that doesn't help (and setting `delaysContentTouches = NO` actually makes the table non-scrollable).  I haven't tried setting these in the new UITableViewCellScrollView because that is private and I didn't want to add new code for `if IOS7, else`...

The `setHighlighted:` calls come from `UIControl touchesBegan:`, `UIControl touchesMoved`, and `UIControl touchesEnded:`.  I never get anything from `UIControl touchesCancelled:` which is what I would expect when the tableView takes over control of the touch events for scrolling.

I can add code if anyone thinks I am doing something wrong, but this seems like more of a concept question to me.

**Why am I not getting `setHighlighted:NO` from `UIControl touchesCancelled:`?**

I have not tried using a non-subclassed UIButton and `setImage:forState:` yet because my highlighted states are just gradient changes and I didn't want to create a UIImage for them.  but I can if I have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the correct way to process this, but since no one else has offered any other solutions I did just find a way to resolve the issue I was having.  Since the default `touchesCancelled` apparently doesn't send a `setHighlight:NO` message to my button sublcass, I overloaded the `touchesCancelled` function in my UIButton subclass and called `[self setHighlighted:NO]`.  That seems to resolve the issue where the buttons stay highlighted when the table scrolls.

Just in case anyone else comes upon this problem in the future.